# Heroku changed files on deployment

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I am having a problem with Heroku that when I deploy my site using node.js. Most of my .js files are changed to my index.html

When I look in the console, many of the .js files are literally clones of my index.html. Of course this makes the website inoperable, and lots of "unexpected token < " because all my js is gone and been replaced with my html.

I a fairly new to Heroku and can not find any references to this type of thing anywhere.

I have tried to re-upload and am getting the same problem. I have gone over my package.json file many time as well as my Procfile.

Any ideas on where I can look to see where to replacement is happening?

Comment: are you committing your local changes to git then uploading ?

Comment: I am having the same issue, github files are correct but when heroku runs and you inspect element you can see that all the javascript and css files are replaced with my index.html page. Its the weirdest issue and I do not know why it does it.